# What the way to use texture in vertex shader novadays?

Tags: xna, shader, monogame, hlsl

What the way to use texture in vertex shader novadays?

I porting old xna example to monogame, and cant find actual solution to a some trick.

sampler2D does not work in VertexShaderFunction
register index exceeded, target doesnt support samplers

as I understand, author used texture color to set height or direction

~

```
texture FlowMapTexture : register(t0);
sampler2D FlowMapSampler : register(s0) = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <FlowMapTexture>;
};
```

~

```
VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
```

~

```
    float2 texCoord = (worldPosition.xz + WorldToFlowMapTexCoord.xy) * WorldToFlowMapTexCoord.zw;
    float2 flowVector = tex2Dlod(FlowMapSampler, float4(texCoord, 0, 0)).rg;

    worldPosition.xz -= flowVector * SquareSize * extendAmount;
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
    output.Color = input.Color;

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found by myself//

I using Shader Model 4 but with Level 9_1 feature set,
which is designed either to use Direct3D11 API on older cards
that do not support "real" feature level 4.0, or embedded devices (read here, phones mostly).

So even if you can use Shader Model 4 syntax,
your shader still needs to comply to the hardware capabilities (which, for level 9.1 is ps2.0).

See msdn blog about Feature Levels here

I just used (/4_0) compiler option instead.